# How to use bootstrap to automatically display users from Active Directory as I type?

Tags: angularjs, html, twitter-bootstrap, ldap, openldap

I have an Active Directory. I am creating a forms page in bootstrap. As I type in a portion of the name, I want the text box to come up with suggestions. For e.g. if I type in Al, it should show Alan, Alice, Alex in a combo style box below and I can select the same using a mouse click. The names come from the Active Directory.

I googled a fair bit, but perhaps I am missing something. If bootstrap + LDAP is not the right technology stack for this, what other lightweight web based options do I have? I can't use C# or Java.

Comment: There are libraries in angularjs which support auto suggestion which you can merge with bootstrap textbox to make it autocompletion box

Answer (score 0):

This code may be helpful for you i am using datalist tag.

```
      <body>
      <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <form class="form-horizontal" style="margin-top:10%;">

                      <div class="form-group has-success">
                            <label for="country" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Select Country</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-2">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" list="countryname" name="country">
                                  <datalist id="countryname">
                                    <div> 
                                      <option value="India">
                                      <option value="France">
                                      <option value="Germany">
                                      <option value="Poland">
                                      <option value="Indonesia">
                                      <option value="USA">
                                      <option value="UK">
                                      <option value="Afghanistan">
                                      <option value="Denmark">
                                      <option value="Finland">    
                                      <option value="Greece">
                                      <option value="Greenland">
                                      <option value="Greenland">
                                      <option value="Greenland">
                                      <option value="Greenland">
                                    </div>   
                                  </datalist>
                            </div>
                      </div> 

                      <div class="form-group has-success">
                        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                          <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                </form>
            </div>    
      </div>  
  </body>
```

The combobox works exactly as autocompletion box.

Comment: This information is all coded statically. What I am looking for is tying up Active Directory with Bootstrap as I type.

Comment: You can use angularjs ng-repeat or ng-option to bring your data from a service, or store your directory inside controller.